# Java IO, Socket server address

Tags: java, sockets, server, client

Newbie in Java with most likely very trivial question: I have an code for Server:

```
public class DateServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(1200);
        try {
            while (true) {
                Socket s1300 = listener.accept();
                try {
                    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(s1300.getOutputStream(), true);
                    out.println(new Date(0).toString());

                } catch (Exception e) {

                } finally {
                    s1300.close();
                }

                }
            } finally {
                listener.close();
            }

    }

}
```

and code for CLient:

```
public class DateClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Socket s = new Socket("local host", 1200);

        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));

        String answer = input.readLine();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, answer);
        System.exit(0);

    }

}
```

and it doesnt work. Obviously there is a problem with Server address but thats what has been consearning me for some time now: how to get an address of an server when its located on same computer? For example, i have few different server classes in the same package / how to get an address.

Answer (score 0):

localhost is normally "localhost", not "local host".

Failing that, try using the "home" address (127.0.0.1)

Comment: Hi Huw, sorry, i just tried it out and it didnt work at all - i tried both options: "localhost" and 127.0.0.1 . Do you maybe have another idea? thanks in advance